# Linear mixed model with skewed residuals

Tags: mixed-model, residuals

I'd like to analyse data of 11 plots with 15 plant individuals on each plot.

A variable was measured on each plant in 9 different years.

So 11 plots with 15 plants on each plot and measurements in 9 years = 1485 observations.

```
  year   id plot  val
1 2000 A_01    A 0.70
2 2000 A_02    A 0.90
3 2000 A_03    A 0.79
4 2000 A_04    A 1.04
5 2000 A_05    A 0.84
6 2000 A_06    A 0.84
...
     year   id plot  val
1480 2008 N_10    N 0.35
1481 2008 N_11    N 0.72
1482 2008 N_12    N 0.36
1483 2008 N_13    N 0.20
1484 2008 N_14    N 0.41
1485 2008 N_15    N 0.51
```

My goal is to find differences on each plot between years as well as differences in each year between the plots.

Thus my analysis in R looks like this so far:

```
library(lme4)
mod <- lmer(val ~ year * plot + (1|id), data = dat)

> summary(mod)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: val ~ year * plot + (1 | id)
   Data: dat

REML criterion at convergence: 299.6

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.0167 -0.5385 -0.0967  0.4548 14.6926 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 id       (Intercept) 5.596e-17 7.481e-09
 Residual             5.992e-02 2.448e-01
```

As I want to calculate p-values to find significant differences between years/plots I think I need to make sure I have normally distributed residuals of the random effects (?).

So I'm looking at the residuals ..

```
mod.res <- ranef(mod)$id$`(Intercept)`
```

.. and find that they are right-skewed:

[image]

So I found that there is the package `robustlmm` that - I think - can take care of that.

```
rmod <- rlmer(val ~ year * plot + (1|id), data = dat)
```

However, now the variance of the random effect is 0

```
Robust linear mixed model fit by DAStau 
Formula: val ~ year * plot + (1 | id) 
   Data: dat 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5596 -0.6193 -0.0762  0.6120 19.8078 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.00000  0.000   
 Residual             0.03766  0.194
```

I am stuck now. What does that mean? How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These models are both telling you that there is no variation between plants. The second model estimates the random intercept variance as zero, while the `lmer` model estimates it as `5.596e-17`, which is $0.000000000000000005596$

So you don't need to fit random intercepts to this data. You can simply use `lm` instead.

As for the residuals, these are not particularly skewed. There are 2, possibly 3, outliers and I would not be overly concerned about this. These residuals are plausibly normally distributed. But to be on the "safe side", you could use robust standard errors - see the `sandwich` package for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I had also already assumed that I don't necessarily need random effects. However, I'd essentially like to carry out a repeated-measures ANOVA and run a Tukey test for group differences, hence I can't simply use `lm` or `aov`, can I? I'll have a look at the sandwich package!

Comment: @beetroot there is no point running repeated measures ANOVA because there is no between-group variation. Why don't you just work with the linear model ? If you want custom contrasts then use `lsmeans`

Comment: Thanks, I am working with aov/lm and lsmeans now, however, I think there's quite some heteroskedasticity in my data, is that a problem when using lsmeans?

Comment: Please post that as a separate question.

Comment: I asked a [new question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229472/is-heteroskedasticity-a-problem-when-calculating-lsmeans), maybe you have some advice ;)